# Unable to import Qiskit Aqua and terra Algorithm QSVM as per the documentation mentioned on Qiskit site

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, qiskit

I am using google colab. I tried installing qiskit library using the following line

```
!pip install qiskit
```

i also tried this

```
!pip install qiskit-aqua
```

I am trying to work on quantum computing SVM model using the following line of code

```
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QSVM
```

Its giving me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-72fec39648aa> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QSVM

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.aqua'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I read through the documentation on this link https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.32/stubs/qiskit.aqua.algorithms.QSVM.html it says which says i have installed and used it correctly but still its giving me the error. Can u please help

Upon research I also found that qiskit.aqua is depricated. but i am not able to use qiskit terra as well.

i tried the similar installations step above but getting the same error as mentioned below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-5d584079ae18> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 from qiskit import Aer
      9 from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
---> 10 from qiskit.terra.algorithms import QSVM

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.terra'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Qiskit Aqua was deprecated](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-aqua#qiskit-aqua-now-deprecated), as you have seen, over two years ago and is no longer supported. A migration guide linked there did list the changes, but the link supplied there is no longer working, however [the original migration notebook](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-aqua/blob/main/docs/tutorials/Qiskit%20Algorithms%20Migration%20Guide.ipynb) source of that is still there, if you should want to look at it, but I will explain below.

As part of that `QSVM` was moved/refactored over to [Qiskit Machine Learning](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/) where it now exists as [QSVC](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.QSVC.html) (and it derives from scikit-learn SVC for compatibility with that library). I would highly recommend looking to this rather than the now unsupported old QSVM. There is a [tutorial here including QSVC](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/tutorials/03_quantum_kernel.html) where you can learn more.

Answer (score 0):

the version got updated.
qiskit.aqua is old version.
For the new version verify the below link:
[Qiskit_new_version](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.28/aqua_tutorials/Qiskit%20Algorithms%20Migration%20Guide.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).