# Can't import QSVM from qiskit machine learning

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

```
from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import QSVM
```

I have written this code to import QSVM from qiskit machine learning but getting getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[7], line 4
    from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import QSVM
ImportError: cannot import name 'QSVM' from 'qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit_machine_learning/algorithms/__init__.py)

Use %tb to get the full traceback.
```

since qiskit.aqua deprecated, I thought of importing QSVM from qiskit ml

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742125/unable-to-import-qiskit-aqua-and-terra-algorithm-qsvm-as-per-the-documentation-m

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import Qiskit Aqua and terra Algorithm QSVM as per the documentation mentioned on Qiskit site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742125/unable-to-import-qiskit-aqua-and-terra-algorithm-qsvm-as-per-the-documentation-m)